# Getting file from content uri for videos taken

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver

I have a method below:

```
private String getRealPathFromUriForVideos(Uri selectedVideoUri) {
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedVideoUri);
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);
    String filePath = "";

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

This works just fine getting the file for videos that hte user selects. However, I want to allow users to also create new videos (from my app) and then get the URI and the file from there. The URI for newly created videos is: **content://media/external/video/media/41**. For selected videos is like **content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A42**.

It works with the second one but not the first one. First one I get IllegalArgumentException because its not a document URI. How can I get the file from the first URI?

Comment: Why would you want 'the file'?

Comment: Need to be able to upload to my server.

Comment: You do not need a file path for that. Just use the uri for that. Please explain exactly why you need a file system path instead of a content scheme.

Comment: I just explained why I needed it and I found a  solution. Thanks. Uploading the object I needed access to the file for my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This works just fine getting the file for videos that hte user selects

It may work in a few situations. It will not work in general. A `Uri` that you get from something like `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not have to represent a file, let alone one that you can access via the filesystem, let alone one that this script-kiddie algorithm will let you access.

> The URI for newly created videos is: content://media/external/video/media/41

Not necessarily. I suppose that there is a way that you get a `Uri` like that for a recorded video, though off the top of my head I cannot think of a recommended way that would give you such a `Uri`. If you are using `MediaRecorder` or `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, you create your own file (and, for `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, your own `Uri` for that file). And, if you are creating your own file, you know where that file is.

> Need to be able to upload to my server

For the video, record to a file that you control, then use that file.

Use some library that lets you upload from a `Uri` or `InputStream`. Otherwise:

- Use `ContentResolver` and `openFileInput()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`
- Create a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Copy the content from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`
- Use your copy for the upload
- Delete your copy when the work is done

You treat a foreign `Uri` as if it were a URL to a Web server: stream the content.

Comment: why treat it that way when there is a way to get the file directly? what about user space issues?

Comment: @KVISH: "when there is a way to get the file directly?" -- because there is no way to get the file directly for an arbitrary `Uri`. The `Uri` might point to a file on internal storage of another app, which you cannot access. The `Uri` might point to a file on removable storage, which you cannot access. The `Uri` might point to a `BLOB` column in a database, which you cannot access. The `Uri` might point to an encrypted file, which you could access but not use. And so on.

Comment: @KVISH: "what about user space issues?" -- there will only be a duplicate copy for a short while, and then only if you decide not to use some library that lets you upload from a `Uri` or an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to get it from the second URI I need this:

```
private String getRealPathFromUriForImagesAndVideo(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```